# With Puppeteer how can I click the parent element of my selector?

Tags: node.js, testing, puppeteer

The markup i have to work with looks like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="myfield" value="Yes" size>
</label>
```

I want to call page.click(selector) with the radio as the selector, but I can't. I don't think it is visible because of the size attribute.

My javascript looks like this:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
const selector = 'input[name="myfield"]';
await page.click(selector);
```

So I would like to target and click the parent label element.

How do I change the value of my selector constant to target the label?

Comment: Please be more specific. How about adding some picture to visualize your current situation? And also add your codes please.

Comment: By "but I can't" you probably mean "but it won't work", so please show what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain very well. By can't, i mean that the element is not visible and therefore i don't believe it can technically be clicked. Therefore I think i need to target the label which is visible, but i don't know how I target it.

Comment: Does `const selector = 'label';` not work or what is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, I didn't explain very well. By can't, i mean that the element is **not visible and therefore i don't believe it can technically be clicked**. Therefore I think i need to target the label which is visible, but i don't know how I target it

not visible or not visible at the moment?

Have you tried to use **`waitForSelector(selector)`** ?

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
const selector = 'input[name="myfield"]';

await page.waitForSelector(selector); // waiting here before click
await page.click(selector);
```

Or something like:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
const selector = 'label';

await page.waitForSelector(selector);

await page.evaluate((_) => {
    document.querySelector('label > input[name="myfield"]').parentElement.click()
});
```